# Show syntax error on browser console in lesscss

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, less

Can this be possible, I wanted to show the code generated errors to the browser's console panel of the browser for **LessCss**...

In the case of any runtime errors or syntax error or any compiler issues, it shows the error hint or line number where the error exactly is? May be using JavaScript or jquery could be the solution.

Can anyone recommend an alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom error and exception handler and [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org)

Edit following SaurabhLP comment : I committed a mistake thinking you use [lessPhp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) to parse your less files to css.

As you use client side parsing with less.js, you can try [fireless](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fireless/).

Hope it helps.